# Creating longitudinal profile for pipeline using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, profile

I have a sewer system in QGIS and i wish to know if is possible to create a longitudinal profile between two manholes, showing the terrain and the pipeline.
In each point (manholes) I have in differents fields: ID, depth, Z terrain and each line has the diameter, but doesn`t matter if the pipeline is not represented with the real diamension and only as a line, the same for terrain, if is only a straight line between manholes is ok, cause the distances are too short and are in a city

Is it possible to create a layout with this graphic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the **plugin** called "**Profile tool**".

If you have more than two points with the z value or/and depth, so you can create a more realistic profile very easily that only the linear calculated slope.

--Edit--

With "profile tool", you can use more than one raster.
First you have to convert your pipeline to a raster layer (convert to point and than TIN interpolation). And than use the pipeline as polyligne and the TIN and the terrain as raster layer.[image]

Comment: I tried but "profile tool" only gives me the terrain profile and i need also de pipeline profile

Comment: For the pipeline, you can calculate longitudinal coordinates. From the manholes  layer, use the expression _x =  line_locate_point( geometry(  get_feature_by_id( 'pipeline',1)) , $geometry )_ and _y = z_.